# How to check if subprocess was killed by signal on Windows

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, signals

### The question

Given a subprocess started in python with code similar to:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
p.communicate()
print('Return code: {}'.format(p.returncode))
```

According to the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CompletedProcess.returncode), it is possible to check whether the subprocess was terminated by a signal:

> A negative value -N indicates that the child was terminated by signal N (POSIX only).

But only on POSIX platforms.

Is there a way to do check if a process was terminated by a signal (do not care which one) on Windows platforms?

### Background

I am running into this issue while running the tests of googletest. The [break-on-failure CLI flag test](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/2fe3bd994b3189899d93f1d5a881e725e046fdc2/googletest/test/googletest-break-on-failure-unittest_.cc) fails on Windows platforms (VC14, VS2017) but works well on POSIX ones (2x Ubuntu, 2x macOS).

Manually on the command line, I get these results:

```
> .\googletest-break-on-failure-unittest_.exe --gtest_break_on_failure
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test case.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from Foo
[ RUN      ] Foo.Bar
<some path>\googletest\test\googletest-break-on-failure-unittest_.cc(52): error: Expected equality of these values:
  2
  3

> echo %ERRORLEVEL%
-2147483645
```

However, the python wrapper that calls this test receives `2147483651` (positive number).

(I just added a print before [this line](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/2fe3bd994b3189899d93f1d5a881e725e046fdc2/googletest/test/gtest_test_utils.py#L290))

Note that these refer to the numbers `0xFFFFFFFF80000003` (negative number) and `0x‭80000003‬` (positive number) in hex and that the return code was not processed any further. (See [here](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/2fe3bd994b3189899d93f1d5a881e725e046fdc2/googletest/test/gtest_test_utils.py#L245))

Why would the return code be changed like this?

PS: Yes, I have checked that `GTEST_OS_WINDOWS` and `GTEST_HAS_SEH` are true in the C++ code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CMD's `ERRORLEVEL` environment variable is a 32-bit signed value. The positive range is 0x00000000-0x7FFFFFFF (0 up to 2147483647), and the negative range is 0x80000000-0xFFFFFFFF (-2147483648 up to -1). When a process exits due to an unhandled exception, the status is usually the exception code, which is typically a 32-bit, signed [`NTSTATUS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc704588) value. That said, nothing stops us from calling `ExitProcess` or `TerminateProcess` with an unsigned exit code that exceeds 0x7FFFFFFF, so a negative `ERRORLEVEL` in CMD by itself does not mean that the process exited abnormally.

In this case, -2147483645 is the `NTSTATUS` code `STATUS_BREAKPOINT` (0x80000003). This originates from the [`gtest_break_on_failure`](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/827515f8a092050901d4eb9fdc1ddbb972f38442/googletest/src/gtest.cc#L4732) option of Google Test, which calls WinAPI [`DebugBreak`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679297(v=vs.85).aspx). For the x86 architecture, the latter function simply executes an `int 3` instruction (software interrupt 3), which is trapped in the kernel to raise a breakpoint exception.

Normally without an attached debugger, this would execute the default Windows unhandled exception handler, which calls on [Windows Error Reporting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Error_Reporting) (see below). But the code linked in the question sets `ExitWithExceptionCode` as the application's unhandled exception filter. This filter simply exits via `exit(exception_pointers->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionCode)`.

As to Unix signals, the Windows kernel doesn't implement them. The C runtime implements the six that are required by standard C. In a console application, the standard `SIGINT` signal is associated with the console's `CTRL_C_EVENT`. The non-standard `SIGBREAK` signal is used for other console control events, including `CTRL_BREAK_EVENT` and `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT`. The default handler for these events calls `ExitProcess(STATUS_CONTROL_C_EXIT)`. Thus, to literally answer the question, to determine whether a process was killed by a console 'signal', check for `STATUS_CONTROL_C_EXIT` (0xC000013A or -1073741510).

---

**Handling an Unhandled Exception**

- If a debugger is attached to the process debug port, the kernel sends it a first-chance exception event. If it doesn't handle the exception, the kernel dispatches the exception to the thread's chain of vectored exception handlers and structured exception handlers (stack-based, checked in reverse from the current frame). We will assume that the exception is not handled by any of them.
- The last frame checked is the frame of the thread startup function, `RtlUserThreadStart`. The handler for this frame, `_C_specific_handler`, is passed a dispatch record that allows it determine the scope's exception filter. This filter in turn calls the unhandled exception filter of the process, given it was previously set via `RtlSetUnhandledExceptionFilter`. At process startup, the initialization routine of kernelbase.dll sets it to the aptly named function, `UnhandledExceptionFilter`.
- If a debugger is attached, `UnhandledExceptionFilter` returns `EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH`. Subsequently, the kernel sends the debugger a second-chance exception event. If the debugger doesn't handle the exception, the kernel tries sending the event to the subsystem, i.e. the Windows session server, csrss.exe. The server in turn relays the fault to the Windows Error Reporting (WER) service, which will ultimately terminate the process.
- If no debugger is attached, `UnhandledExceptionFilter` calls the application's unhandled exception filter, if it was previously set via [`SetUnhandledExceptionFilter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680634). If the application filter returns `EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION` or `EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER`, then `UnhandledExceptionFilter` returns this value to the frame handler.
- If the application hasn't set its own filter or if its filter returns `EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH`, then `UnhandledExceptionFilter` next checks the job, process, and thread error modes for the flag `SEM_NOGPFAULTERRORBOX`. This flag disables error reporting, in which case the filter simply returns `EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER`.
- If error reporting is allowed, `UnhandledExceptionFilter` calls on the Windows Error Reporting (WER) service. With WER in the loop, the behavior ultimately depends on how it's configured in the registry, group policy, and the default behavior for the current Windows version. WER may create and attach a debugger process, based on the system "AeDebug" settings. If it attaches a debugger, `UnhandledExceptionFilter` returns `EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH`, just like it would had a debugger already been attached. Otherwise it returns `EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER`.
- Ultimately if it executes the exception handler for an 'unhandled' exception, the stack is first unwound to the `RtlUserThreadStart` frame via `RtlUnwindEx`, which will call any `finally` termination handlers in the intervening frames. The exception handler's execution context is restored via `RtlRestoreContext`, and the exception code gets set in the integer return register (e.g. `rax` in x64). At last, the handler self-terminates via `NtTerminateProcess(NtCurrentProcess(), exceptionCode)`.