# How to kill python using taskkill on windows without /F

Tags: python, windows, taskkill

[The accepted answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54182993/how-to-check-if-subprocess-was-killed-by-signal-on-windows) elaborates how the signal for a process exit can be determined on windows.
But if we launch python in the command line using `python`
And try to kill it using task manager or task kill like so:

`taskkill /FI "IMAGENAME eq python.exe"
ERROR: The process with PID 5616 could not be terminated.
Reason: This process can only be terminated forcefully (with /F option).`

Using the `/F` option always sets the `%errorlevel%` to 1.
Is there a way to terminate the python process on windows where the process return code retains the signal information.

EDIT 1: The comments and possible solution possible duplicates of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23197669/send-wm-close-message-to-a-process-with-no-window/).

Comment: taskkill sends a `WM_CLOSE` message to the top-level and message-only windows. But this instance of python.exe has no windows, so it tells you that it will have to terminate via `TerminateProcess` (i.e. forcefully) with an exit status of 1.

Comment: If python.exe is started with a new console, e.g. via `start python.exe`, it will be seen by the API as the effective owner of the console window, in which case taskkill will send `WM_CLOSE` to the console, which will in turn send `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT` to Python's registered console control handlers. If the python.exe process doesn't handle this event by exiting on its own within 5 seconds, the system will terminate the process with the status code `STATUS_CONTROL_C_EXIT` (0xC000013A or -1073741510).

Comment: Thanks That narrows down the search, I will start a different question for a complete solution.

Comment: Is this python.exe process running a script that you wrote? If so you can create a message-only window (not visible) owned by a dedicated thread in order to get the normal close message from taskkill. Otherwise, run Python from the command prompt via `start "" /w python.exe "<script>"`. The `/w` option forces `start` to wait and set `errorlevel`.

Comment: In my python program I use popen to launch a second python process, wait on the result but want to know whether it exited because it was killed.

Comment: With `subprocess.Popen` you can pass `creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` to ensure a child console process allocates a new console. It will thus own the console and be killable via taskkill without /f. However, if it handles `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT`, it may exit cleanly with an exit status of 0. Also, if the process is forcefully terminated, you will not have anyway to know. System utilities usually terminate a process with an exit status of 1, which is just a generic status code meaning an unsuccessful exit.